# Play Framework: NoSuchFieldError when reverse routing

Tags: playframework

Here is my `common.routes` file:

```
GET     /emails/:deflated   controllers.common.Emails.viewInBrowser(deflated)
```

... and here my controller:

```
package controllers.common

object Emails extends Controller {

  def viewInBrowser(deflated: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    GZip.inflate(deflated) match {
      case Success(inflated) => Ok(Html(inflated))
      case Failure(e) => {
        Logger.warn(s"error inflating email from url", e)
        val support = configuration.getString("application.emails.support")
        BadRequest(views.html.badRequest(Messages("common.error.invalidOrMalformedUrl", support)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code above works fine... but if I reverse route like this

```
import controllers.common.routes
...

val sslEnabled = configuration.getBoolean("ssl").getOrElse(false)
val emailUrl = routes.Emails.viewInBrowser(true).absoluteURL(sslEnabled)
```

... I always the the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Emails
at utils.common.RoutesHelper$.emailUrl(RoutesHelper.scala:51)
at services.common.DefaultEmailComponent$DefaultRichBody.apply(EmailComponent.scala:64)
at services.common.DefaultEmailServiceComponent$DefaultEmailService.sendEmail(EmailServiceComponent.scala:81)
at utils.auth.EmailHelper$.sendUserVerificationEmail(EmailHelper.scala:32)
at controllers.auth.Users$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$60$$anonfun$apply$61.apply(Users.scala:381)
at controllers.auth.Users$$anonfun$create$1$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$60$$anonfun$apply$61.apply(Users.scala:379)
at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)[ERROR] [05/30/2014 16:35:05.350] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
```

Any idea? I verified everything I could (configuration files, routes, controllers)... but no way to figure out what the problem is. I'm using Play 2.2.3.

**UPDATE**

What's very strange is that I've tried to move my `Emails` controller into another package (i.e. `models`) and in that case reverse routing works again. Is there a bug somewhere in Play?

Comment: Do you use subprojects?
Seems it is related to this issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1123

Comment: Yes I do... and I read this issue but it didn't help. Anyway thank you for your comment.

Comment: Ok... Nevertheless I posted in the answer the solution that helped me to solve the similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, if there are routes defined in the same package in the root project and in one of the sub-projects the generated sub-project `routes` object hides the same object from root project and all the code referencing the old `routes` object becomes erroneous.

E.g. if the `routes` file in the root project contains a route

```
GET /path       mypackage.MyController.someAction
```

and the `subproject.routes` file contains a route

```
GET /otherPath  mypackage.MyOtherController.otherAction
```

both projects generate the `mypackage.routes` objects during build and one of them hides the another one in the runtime.

The solution is to define all the sub-project routes in its own packages that are not presented in the root project.

Comment: The problem in my project was that I shared the same Asset controller in all my sub-projects... In my opinion this would make sense, but as reported in may mailing lists this is a compiler limitation. Anyway, many thanks for your support ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After having spent the whole night to figure out how to make this work, I've just modified the routes like this

```
GET     /emails/:deflated   controllers.common.webmail.Emails.viewInBrowser(deflated)
```

and my controller like this:

```
package controllers.common.webmail

object Emails extends Controller {
  ...
}
```

Renaming the package to `controllers.common.webmail` solves the problem and reverse routing works now... but don't ask me why :-(

I guess there should be a bug in Play. I hope that helps.